# Как получить координаты мыши в Java относительно окна приложения?

Tags: java

Я получаю координаты мыши с помощью метода MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; но он отображает реальные координаты курсора на экране(например, у меня есть окон с изображением. Передвинув окно в правую часть экрана и нажав на изображение, а потом проделав то же самое только передвинув окно в левую часть я получаю разные значения.) Мне же необходимо получить координаты курсора относительно окна(если я нажму на левый верхний угол окна метод должен вернуть нулевые координаты).

Comment: Узнавайте положение окна относительно монитора и нехитрыми математическими действиями узнавайте нужные вам координаты

Comment: и какие же это действия?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Важный вопрос - где вы получаете координаты? Если в обработчике событий мыши, то лучше воспользоваться методами `getX()` и `getY()` события [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html). Если же всё-таки есть нужда использовать `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()`, то есть простой способ преобразовать координаты экрана в координаты окна:

```
SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(MouseInfo.getPointerIn‌​fo().getLocation(), component)
```